# What is the difference between the method writeChar and writeShort in java.io.DataOutputStream class?

Tags: java, io, outputstream

I am currently learning basic I/O of java. Please see the following code:

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
public class TestIO {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try(DataOutputStream out=new 
    DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("e:\\ccc.txt"))){

        out.writeShort(67);
        out.writeChar(67);

    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

In the output ccc.txt file, I get the following output:

```
 C C
```

I understand that both methods write two bytes to the outputstream and the binary string of 67 is 1000011 which represents the capital letter C in ASCII or anyother code. The space before C is the byte 0000 0000 read by the methods.

However, what is the difference between the two methods if they both simply write two bytes to the outputstream?I was expecting that writeShort can write two bytes to the outputstream and then transfer it back to integer. In other words, how can I directly write the integer 67 to a file,not converting it to a character?

---

Let me ask this question in a different way, under what circumstance can these two methods generate different results? I need a real-world example. Thanks!

Comment: Note that there are encodings where 67 *isn't* the encoded form of `C`. But in Java, `'C'` will *always* have a value of 67, because it's always UTF-16.

Comment: @Ingo, actually writeShort(33333) doesn't give a compile time error? Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @user3225698 This is probably because the argument is declared as int. If the argument of writeChar is also declared int, then you wont be able to produce different results. If it is char, then try writeChar(77777).

Comment: @user3225698 It is actually int, but think of it like: If Java is changed so that *char* uses 3 bytes, then it will make a difference. One needs not think backwards like: *I want to write 2 bytes, which method to use?* (in that case use writeByte twice) but: *I need to write an X, so I use the writeX method.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the confusion comes from trying to write text using classes designed to write binary.  If you want to write/read text use Writer/Reader classes.  If you want binary use OutputStream/InputStream.

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("ccc.txt");
pw.println('C');
pw.println(67);
pw.close();
```

will produce a file which looks like

```
C
67
```

but in reality you have written a file which contains bytes 67, 19, 16, 54, 55, 19, 16 i.e it is now 7 bytes long.

> what is the difference between the two methods if they both simply write two bytes to the outputstream?

They do exactly the same thing in this case.  The difference only matters for the readChar / readShort.

```
public final void writeChar(int v) throws IOException {
    out.write((v >>> 8) & 0xFF);
    out.write((v >>> 0) & 0xFF);
    incCount(2);
}

public final void writeShort(int v) throws IOException {
    out.write((v >>> 8) & 0xFF);
    out.write((v >>> 0) & 0xFF);
    incCount(2);
}
```

You can see the code is the same.

> I was expecting that writeShort can write two bytes to the outputstream and then transfer it back to integer.

A file only contains a stream of bytes.

> In other words, how can I directly write the integer 67 to a file,not converting it to a character?

That is what you are doing.  A file only contains bytes.  When you read text you are converting these bytes into `char`s, or `short`s or `int`s depending on how you read them.

Comment: Thanks. I have read the source code before. My confusion is: In the real world, under what circumstance, these two methods can generate different results?If they are exact the same, why bother having two method?

Comment: @user3225698 Which method would you have and what would you call it so it is clear that you can write either a `short` or a `char`?  If I have `readShort` and `readChar` which write method would I use?

Comment: @user3225698 Most likely it is there to keep the documentation and usage simple.  If you start saying there is only one method then developers will start asking, why is there one write and two read methods and what happens to my char when I write it as a short etc

Answer (score 1):

> However, what is the difference between the two methods if they both simply write two bytes to the outputstream?

This sounds trite, but: one takes a `char`, the other takes a `short`. Those types aren't convertible to each other, and you use them at different times. Even though a `char` is just a 16-bit unsigned integer, its expected use is for UTF-16 code units; you wouldn't (or at least shouldn't) use it to store values you *think of* as numbers... and the opposite is true for `short`.

So if you've got a `char` that you want to write, use `writeChar`. If you've got a `short`, use `writeShort`. In both cases you'd want to read with the corresponding method.

Comment: Corrected `writeHsort` -> `writeShort`

Answer (score 0):

```
writeShort(int v)
```

Writes two bytes to the output stream to represent the value of the argument.

```
writeChar(int v)
```

Writes a char value, which is comprised of two bytes, to the output stream.

**You could use:**

```
writeInt(int v)
```

Writes an int value, which is comprised of four bytes, to the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you do not want to use `writeChar()` to write text data to output streams. You'll want to use a [Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) with the proper encoding.

If you need to output a binary 16-bit signed integer for some reason, you can use `writeShort`, but if you really need that much control you may want to use a [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) instead.